Deploy Nextjs app with React Big Calendar on AWS Codebuild failed
I encountered an error while deploying my project on AWS CodeBuild. The error message was related to react-big-calendar library, but I am unsure what caused it. I'm using Nextjs 13.4.2, Node 18.6.0. Can someone please help me troubleshoot? Thank you.
The build failed error:
Module not found: Package path ./helpers/esm/callSuper is not exported from package /codebuild/output/.../@babel/runtime
I tried to build on my local computer but it succeed

I resolved it by downgrading its version to 1.5.2.
